# Which two numbers replaces the question mark?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

[image]

I was solving some number puzzles. I am finding difficulty in  solving this puzzle: which two numbers will replace the question marks? I need answer with explanation.

Comment: Hi there do you have a source for this puzzle? If so, could you please include a link or a reference to it at the end of your question? Thank you :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answer is:

> 8 and 1

Explanation:

> Reading each row as 3 separate 2-digit numbers, the central number equals the average of the left and right hand numbers.

Comment: Good answer! I have edited it to include spoiler blocks so that people can attempt it themselves without having the answer immediately spoiled for them. Happy Puzzling!